# Angular Global CSS styles Issue

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I created a an Angular project and I cannot set properly the Bootstrap downloaded css styles. 
Even if I followed some instructions: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-global-css-styles/

Styles downloaded from: https://bootstrapmade.com/laura-free-creative-bootstrap-theme/

[image]

It was supposed to look like a nav-bar:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried putting styles in the same dir as the `angular.json` and seeing whether just `style.css` works?

Comment: @RobEvans well style.css works well, only that the styles from assets folder don't. Tho this isn't a big issue as long as style.css works. Thank you for your suggestion:)

Comment: How about something like: ```"assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/assets/css/bootstrap.css"
            ],``` Seems like the assets list has `src/assets` but perhaps you're trying to include `src/style.css` and its out of scope?

Comment: "../src/assets/css/style.css" yes I added it in angular.json. src/style.css isn't out of space. What do you think, might it be related to the fact that in index.html I cannot run the project with the added "<link href="assets/vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">" elements fro src/assets/vendors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to put the bootstrap stuff (js, base and theme css) in the header of your **index.html**

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</header>
```

Comment: Hi Marc, I added mentioned script tags and it worked perfectly! Thank you very much for your help :)